# Don't create view folder on rails generate controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way with the usual generators config to turn OFF the creation of the view folders and action templates when you run a `rails generate controller`?

I can't find an option anywhere and the code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/33d92bf69ec5e6f385612b69a6295f5a80332ef8/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/controller/controller_generator.rb) doesn't show me any pointers.

We are likely going to be building our own controller / resource generators at some point anyway, for our API, but I was curious if there was a way to turn off this annoyance in the meantime.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's not a well documented feature, but try to add `--skip-template-engine` (alias `--no-template-engine`) option to the command.

```
rails generate controller foo bar --skip-template-engine
```

demo on a dummy app:

```
rails g controller my_controller index show --no-template-engine
      create  app/controllers/my_controller_controller.rb
       route  get "my_controller/show"
       route  get "my_controller/index"
      invoke  test_unit
      create    test/functional/my_controller_controller_test.rb
      invoke  helper
      create    app/helpers/my_controller_helper.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/unit/helpers/my_controller_helper_test.rb
      invoke  assets
      invoke    coffee
      create      app/assets/javascripts/my_controller.js.coffee
      invoke    scss
      create      app/assets/stylesheets/my_controller.css.scss
```

Comment: Marking as answered, though its not exactly what I was going for.  I was looking for a simple generators option to throw into the application.rb.  We'll end up just writing our own generators I think, for other reasons, but at least I know there's not something obvious in the options I'm missing.  Thanks!

Comment: Also use `--skip-assets` or `--skip-helper` to forego those as well

Comment: Add `--skip-test-framework` if you'd like to skip the test files aswell.

Answer (score 37):

To skip views from being generated with your controller, disable the template engine.

**Once:**

```
rails g controller ControllerName action1 action2 --skip-template-engine
```

Note that every `--skip` option also has an aliased `--no` option.

**Default:**

```
# config/application.rb

config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine false
end

# OR

config.generators.template_engine = false
```

---

If you have an API-only application (no front end), you may also want to skip assets and helpers from being generated with your controllers.

**Once:**

```
rails g controller api/users --no-helper --no-assets --no-template-engine
```

**Default:**

```
# config/application.rb

config.generators do |g|
  g.assets false
  g.helper false
  g.template_engine false
end

# OR

config.generators.assets = false
config.generators.helper = false    
config.generators.template_engine = false
```

---

Disabling assets skips stylesheets *and* javascripts from being generated. If you only want to skip one, use `--no-stylesheets` or `--no-javascripts`, or in `config/application.rb` use:

```
config.generators.stylesheets = false
config.generators.javascripts = false
```

---

If your default configuration skips something from being generated (e.g. assets and helpers) but you need them in one case, you can generate them like so:

```
rails g controller foo --helper --assets --skip
```

where `--skip` skips generating files that already exist.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. Good to know how some of these things work.

Comment: I use rails 5 and it warn `Expected string default value for '--template-engine'; got false (boolean)` but replace `false` with `nil` works fine - silently disable.

Comment: config.api_only = true does the same job ?

Answer (score 5):

Just thought I'd try underscoring the --skip-template-engine flag to see if it worked in a generator and it worked a charm! No view templates generated from a `bin/rails g controller` command in a Rails 4.2 application.

Try:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine false
end
```

A little late I know but these things stick around in Google! ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you're creating an API with no front end, you can go ahead and use `rails new --api`. However, I don't recommend this option if you do plan to create a front end (for example a single page app) because it turns a lot of things off, including the asset pipeline.