# How to avoid view directory creation after run controller generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-generators

I'm trying to run this command:

`rails generate controller users --no-helper --no-assets --no-view-specs --no-controller-specs`

to create the controller file only. But, I can't find a way to **avoid view directory creation**. How can I do this?

Comment: You should look into the answers to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406370/dont-create-view-folder-on-rails-generate-controller

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running a generator it'd be easiest to create the `users_controller.rb` file yourself and populate it with

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
end
```

Comment: The context is more complex than that. I'm using the generator inside my own generator like this: `generate "controller #{resource_path} --no-helper --no-assets --no-view-specs --no-controller-specs"`

Comment: Could you just delete the folder directly after you create it by adding something like `Dir.delete("app/views/#{ folder_name }")`

Comment: I know I can do that. I just want to know if there is a way to do it using the generator